# Short circuit evaluation is C++?

Tags: c++

I've been reading the C++ for dummies book and I'm loving it! I'm on the section where he is talking about short circuit evaluation. Here is my understanding of short circuit evaluation.

> Short circuit evaluation is only applied to bitwise operators, for example AND && and OR ||. So if condition1 is not true then the whole statement is not true!

I've been trying to get my head around this concept by using the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool condition1 = true;
    bool condition2 = false;

    if (condition1 && condition2)
    {
        cout << "The statement is true!";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "The statement is false.";
    }
}
```

But I'm returned with the statement being false have I grasped this concept the wrong way?

Comment: Side note: `&&` and `||` are *logical* operators and short-circuit. The *bitwise* operators `&` and `|` are guaranteed to never short-circuit even for values with all bits cleared or set.

Answer (score 5):

Short circuit evaluation isn't about true or false.  It's about not evaluating part of an expression if you can predict the result without it.   Since `false && whatever()` returns false regardless of `whatever()` you don't need to call `whatever()`.

Your code doesn't demonstrate this at all.  You simply can't demonstrate this with `true` and `false`.  You need a side effect.

Say `whatever()` throws an exception.  Now we'll know if it was called and if it wasn't.  You could also have it display on the console.

Short circuit evaluation can be thought of two ways.  An efficient way to avoid unneeded work, and as a way to control flow.  Of the two, the second is much more meaningful.  Here is a common idiom that uses it:

```
if (foo != null && foo->isValid()) {
    foo->doStuff();
}
```

`foo->isValid()` would dereference a null and cause undefined behavior if `foo` is `null`.  Here, short circuit evaluation prevents that by simply not calling `foo->isValid()`.  It can do that because "false and anything" will always stay false.  That c++ actually does this is called short circuit evaluation.  It also works with "true or anything".  Just remember it evaluates from left to right.  So you use the left to control the execution of the right.

Comment: You should be using `foo->isValid()` rather than `foo.isValid()`.

Comment: i think by null pointer exception you really mean undefined behavior / segfault. null pointer exception is java

Comment: @ChrisBeck Thank you kindly as well.  I've been staring at Java for too long.

Answer (score 1):

The short circuit evaluation only works in cases where you can guarantee after evaluating the first operand that the end result won't be influenced by the second operand.

So for `&&`, if the first operand evaluates to `true`, you can't logically guarantee the result and have to evaluate the second operand (remember: `&&` only returns `true` if both operands are `true`!). However, if the first operand is `false`, we can skip the evaluation of the second operand, since it won't change the result (`false`).

Nearly the same applies for `||`, although you short circuit on a first operand that evaluates to `true` (since `||` returns `true` if either operand is `true`).

This might cause problems (or can be abused) when one or both operands are function calls, e.g. `doStuff() || reportFailure()`. `reportFailure()` will only be called if `doStuff()` returned `false`. This can sometimes cause confusion, especially if the code afterwards relies on some side-effect of `reportFailure()`.

Comment: @The mysterious downvoter: would you please explain what can be done to improve on this answer?

Answer (score 1):

The text you quoted would convince me never to let anyone buy this book.

&& and || are *not* bitwise operators, they are logical operators. & and | are bitwise operators, and they are not short-circuited.

Short-circuit operations are obviously different for && and ||. If you evaluate condition1 && condition2, then if condition1 is false, you know that condition1 && condition2 is false, so you don't evaluate condition2. If condition1 is true, then you don't know the result of the && yet; you need to evaluate condition2.

For ||, it is the exact opposite. If condition1 is true, then condition1 || condition2 is known to be true, so condition2 is not evaluated. If condition1 is not true, then we need to evaluate condition2.

Answer (score 1):

The text you quoted is a bit sloppy (if for no other reason than `&&` and `||` are not bitwise operators).

In the expression `a && b`, the expression `b` will be evaluated if and only if the expression `a` evaluates to true.  If `a` evaluates to false, then `a && b` will evaluate to false regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` isn't evaluated at all:

```
a      b      result   b is evaluated
-      -      ------   --------------
true   true   true     yes
true   false  false    yes
false  ??     false    no
```

In the expression `a || b`, `b` will be evaluated if and only if `a` evaluates to false.  If `a` is true, then `a || b` will evaluate to true regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` isn't evaluated at all:

```
a      b      result   b is evaluated
-      -      ------   --------------
true   ??     true     no
false  true   true     yes
false  false  false    yes
```

Unlike most operators in C, `&&` and `||` force left-to-right evaluation and they introduce sequence points (`a` is evaluated and all side effects are applied before `b` is evaluated), so expressions like `x++ && x++` are well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler sees the if statement:

if(condition1 && condition2)

> It says to itself, condition 1 is true, so now my users wants to know
>   if condition2 is also true.....hmmmm..... condition2 is false,
>   therefore this statement is false

If you want to see a short circuit then refactor your if state to be:

if(condition2 && condition1)

Now the compiler will reason it out something like this:

> "Ok, I have an if statement.  The first argument is false.  Now user
>   wants me to 'and' it with something. But I don't even have to look at
>   condtion1 since I'm sure this if statement evaluates to false.

So the compiler doesn't even bother to evaluate condtion1.